# What are the two hornpipes in "Two Hornpipes" from the Pirates of the Caribbean

Tags: identify-this-song, soundtrack, folk

In the soundtrack to the second *Pirates of the Caribbean*, there is a track titled "Two hornpipes" ([Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4WCdeltSsyM)). I can only hear one in it, and it sounds rather similar to the [Lamplighter's Hornpipe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KM5TOjRNSDQ), but not quite the same. Is this an original composition based on the lamplighter's hornpipe, or something completely different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More research indicates that the song is a version of Fischer's Hornpipe.